# Full-text search in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, full-text-search, sql-server-2012

I am breaking my head over this issue for hours and cant find the solution. I have three work environments and we use SQL Server 2012. Problem is FTS is not working.

I have pulled the properties for FTS for same table, and only difference is in the "Full Text Index FileGroup".

Let's say that FTS catalog is named hello. The environment where it works has "Full Text Index FileGroup" property set exactly like: ftfg_hello, while the one that does not work has it set like: PRIMARY.

When I say it does not work, I mean I get the results, but it takes forever to get them.

I wonder does that property is a problem? Should I look for something else?

BTW: Environment that does not work is set on Amazon Instance RDS.

Thank you for your time

Comment: I may have found problem. select * From sys.fulltext_catalogs command on working place gives me for PATH a real c://etc path, while the sam ecommand on Amazon INstance server returns NULL. Is that it?

Comment: Have you considered submitting a support ticket with amazon?

Comment: Yes. I wrote a ticket to them. I hope they will resolve it :(

Comment: Actually I wrote on forum. I have no idea how to write a ticket without paying extra money :(